# composer install error "Could not parse URElasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\InvalidArgumentException : Could not parse URII"

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, composer-php

I have installed the elasticsearch(version 6.4) in my local system. And I have to install [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php) package via composer. And it installed perfectly but at the end, I'm getting following error

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>       Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
>       Nothing to install or update
>       Generating optimized autoload files
>   Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   @php artisan package:discover
>
> Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\InvalidArgumentException  : Could not parse URI
>       at /var/www/html/renthisto/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ClientBuilder.php:669
>      665|     {
>      666|         $parts = parse_url($host);
>      667| 
>      668|         if ($parts === false) {
>      669|             throw new InvalidArgumentException("Could not parse 
>       URI");
>      670|         }
>      671| 
>      672|         if (isset($parts['port']) !== true) {
>      673|             $parts['port'] = 9200;
>
> Exception trace:
>    1   Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::extractURIParts("http://")
>   /var/www/html/renthisto/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ClientBuilder.php:625
>   2   Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::buildConnectionsFromHosts()
>    /var/www/html/renthisto/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/ClientBuilder.php:562
>   Please use the argument -v to see more details.
>   Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Here's my composer file

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.8",
    "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^6.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
    "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

I didn't find any solution to this. I have following version 
(PHP-7.2)
(Laravel-5.6)
(Elasticsearch-6.4) in my local system.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the service.php config file, replacing the hosts worked for me.

Before(where search host was "localhost:9200")

```
'search' => [
    'enabled' => env('SEARCH_ENABLED', false),
    'hosts' => explode(',', env('SEARCH_HOST')),
]
```

After replacing the hosts, It worked.

```
'search' => [
    'enabled' => env('SEARCH_ENABLED', false),
    'hosts' => ['127.0.0.1'],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In file .env add

```
ELASTICSEARCH_ENABLED=true
ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=localhost:9200
```

Comment: Dear @Aleksandr, welcome to SO. Please add an explanation to your answer _why_ the change works in context of the question. Let me know if you have any questions about that.